# Other options for a Rebol editor|IDE?

Tags: ide, editor, rebol

I currently use Programmer's Notepad with the Rebol syntax scheme.  It's not bad--does any insightful person have another suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

For my Windows programming work I use the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor, but I'm not sure if it does Rebol?

Comment: The question is specifically about a Rebol editor. Zeus doesn't support Rebol as far as I can see.

Answer (score 4):

Another windows option is TextPad. It is commercial but it is quite a useful editor.

There are 2 Rebol syntax files available from the official site

http://www.textpad.com/add-ons/synn2t.html

I also wrote a TextPad syntax file generator uploaded it to rebol.org

http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=textpad-syngen.r

It is probably quite easy to modify this script to support other editors.

Answer (score 4):

**vim**.

---

Especially with the following binding in your _vimrc/.vimrc:

```
 nnoremap <Leader>fr :w<CR>:silent ! %<CR>
```

---

In normal mode, <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> saves your current file and executes it: (<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> is a memo for 'fast-run')

1. <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> save current file
2. <kbd>:silent</kbd> execute without messages: <kbd>!</kbd> open shell <kbd>%</kbd> paste current file name <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Leader</kbd> is usually <kbd>\</kbd> key, I have this mapped to <kbd>spacebar</kbd>. In case anyone is interested on how to do that, post a comment.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing about the Leader mapping in vim, please post it.

Comment: If you're using Vim for REBOL, I have a decent syntax highlighting module for it [here](https://github.com/Prosumma/vim-rebol).

Answer (score 3):

Programmer’s Notepad better than Crimson Editor with Code Folding and Great Project Management
http://www.pnotepad.org/

It's opensource so you can even modify it in C++

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, there is Crimson Editor or E with the REBOL bundle.

For Mac, there is TextMate.

Emacs, I believe has a REBOL syntax too.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime Text is a really nice Windows editor (commercial, but reasonably priced) that supports TextMate configurations (well, at least for syntax and snippets) so if you manage to get a REBOL bundle from somewhere, you can use it with this.

SciTE also has REBOL syntax coloring support because the Scintilla editor component it's based on includes this.

Notepad++ should also support REBOL syntax coloring, being Scintilla based, but as it is currently distributed, the support is not compiled in. If you're so inclined, you could probably compile it yourself and add the support back in. It might be worth it because Notepad++ is quite a good editor too.

I can't include proper links because I don't have enough rep, but this should do:
  www.sublimetext.com
  www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html
  www.scintilla.org/index.html
  notepad-plus-plus.org

Answer (score 2):

http://rebol.wik.is/index.php?title=Notepad%2b%2b

which is a REBOL plugin for Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

I use JEdit which not only has REBOL syntax highlighting but also auto-indenting. It has most of the features you'd expect from a text editor (e.g. block selection, configurable keyboard shortcuts).

There are versions for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux so if you choose to work cross-platform you won't need to learn a new editor. The web page is Jedit.org[1](http://www.jedit.org/)

Comment: Weird to use this java heavy and ugly software for rebol :)

Answer (score 0):

I use UltraEdit.

with its advanced project, syntax highlighting, macro, command-line control and total keyboard shortcut configuration, per language and project, you can program the editor to do just about all of what you need at a single click of the mouse, or keyboard.

my setup starts rebol on any file, and assigns a launch "default project script " to a shortcut, so wherever I am in the files, I still launch the project's relevant script.  change project, it will run that new project's scripts.  another key for unit tests, another key for "find in all opened files, etc, etc..

also, the actual text-exiting, when combined with a few macros which create functions, objects, and more using the clipboard and "currently highlighted" text makes it much faster than any Visual IDE including MSVC.

ultra edit itself has thousands of other advanced features, and they all work... really they do.

I've tried other editors and they always fall short when I start to push them.

yeah, you have to buy it... but its cheap (like one or two hours of your life salary ;-)

so considering you might use it for several months or years... its a cheap investment.

also, ultra edit is now released on linux and the mac port is just around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

I use EditPlus for several years, it is not free but not expensive. It has Rebol syntax highlighting file (downloadable from its web site).
It is especially useful & very fast if you work with huge files (over 100 mb) or with lots of files (say 300 files.), find & replace takes a second.

Answer (score 0):

For syntax highlighting and a simple autocomplete, you can use http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/.

It's free and open source with several nice features, including folder browsing while editing, which I personally find very useful.

There is also a bunch of other languages supported in case you want to take a closer look and give this editor a chance.